# What does this mean: "it's all too easy to come up short when someone has their eyes to the sky ."

Tags: meaning

Can someone please explain to me what the bolded sentence means in the following passage

> Anyone who’s been to Sonic knows what unmet expectations feel like. If you’re a small business owner, you’ve probably come to hate the verb “expect” more than any other. Customers have a whole lot of dreams about what you can deliver, and **it’s all too easy to come up short when someone has their eyes to the sky**.

Comment: Without knowing fully where that quote is from, and assuming it's talking about the large US fast-food franchise, "Sonic", it seems to be saying that smaller businesses have a hard time living up the expectations of customers that are used to the customer satisfaction offered by large chains.  The "eyes to the sky" means that they're expectations are high.

Comment: But what is the meaning for" to come up short" here? Does it mean "to fail"?

Comment: Yes, to "come up short" means to fail in fulfilling the customers' expectations.

Comment: Although Kristina's explanation about "eyes to the sky" is correct, you should know that this isn't, to my knowledge, a standard English phrase. It actually sounds rather odd to me.

Comment: "Come up short" doesn't necessarily mean to fail completely though: it implies that you did partially fulfill some of their expectations, but not fully.

Comment: @user124384 While it's not a common phrase, the meaning of the metaphor should be pretty obvious in context.

Comment: "Come up short" is an idiomatic expression meaning to fail to meet some goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bolded phrase means **it's easy to fail to meet high expectations.**

When someone has their "eyes to the sky" they are expecting a lot, and when that happens it's easy to "come up short" or "fall short of" or "fail to meet" those high expectations.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to keep your nose to the grindstone, your ducks in a row, and your feet on the ground when your head is in the clouds. Just sayin.